# Control becomes visible in Outlook addin with WindowsAPI

Tags: c#, winapi, outlook-addin

I'm finishing up an outlook add-in and i'm running into a weird issue. I am using the windows api (user32.dll) to disable a control on the Outlook New Message Window or a Message Compose window.

This works fine. However if the user adds/removes the BCC field the Window redraws or something and the disabled button becomes visible again. This also happens if the user is responding to a message that isn't the latest in the 'conversation' and outlook will animate the window with the latest message error. The user32.dll function i'm using is ShowWindow(hwnd, WindowShowStyle.Hide)

tl;dr: Disabled/Hidden Control becomes visible again on redraw.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Anydraw back to using DestroyWindow(hwnd); on a control?

Comment: *"Anydraw back to using DestroyWindow(hwnd); on a control?"* - A control is a window, so calling `DestroyWindow` on your control is fine. Unless it isn't your control. In that case the implications are the same as if you walked into a stranger's home, and randomly destroyed a piece of their furniture. The owner may not care, but I wouldn't count on it.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for the reply. I think the analogy was perfect. If I needed to destroy/hide a control that wasn't mine.. 

Is there any feasible amount of testing I could do to make sure of the ramifications or am I just playing with fire?

Comment: You are playing with fire, and there's little you can do in the way of testing, to find out how far the fire will spread. You are dealing with unknown code. The situation becomes worse, if you read the documentation for [DestroyWindow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632682.aspx): *"A thread cannot use DestroyWindow to destroy a window created by a different thread."* Unless you get your code onto the right thread, the outcome is undefined.

Comment: @IInspectable I hate to keep bothering you but if I could just ask one more question. I have found that sending WM_CLOSE will achieve the same result of 'hiding' the control. Is that just as dangerous? Is the outcome still undefined in your opinion? I will end by saying, thank you, you have shared a wealth of knowledge with me today.

Comment: Posting (and sending) messages across threads is safe. The message will be handled on the owning thread, and everything is in a consistent state. That is as far as the window manager is concerned. It is still impossible to know, how the application will respond to either the `WM_CLOSE` message, or the missing control. It might continue to work as expected, or fail in any number of ways. Unless the functionality to disable controls is exposed through the [Outlook Object Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268893.aspx), all attempts are brittle at best.

Comment: What control are you disabling in the email form/window? A Ribbon control? Or one of the controls in the header?